# Jquery add/remove class on checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, addclass

im having problems with the following.

No class gets added or removed - no errors on log

Whats wrong?

JQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
//reset
$j( "input[name*='mycheckbox']" ).prop("checked", false);
$j( "input[name*='mycheckbox']").click(function(){

   if (!$j(this).is(":checked")) {

       //unchecked
    $j(this).removeClass("selected");  

    } else {
        //checked

    $j(this).addClass("selected"); 
    }

})

})
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input name="mycheckbox[]" value="xxx" type="checkbox">&nbsp;xxx<br />
<input name="mycheckbox[]" value="yyy" type="checkbox">&nbsp;yyy
```

Comment: Did you try making the selector more generic?

Comment: [**WORKING FINE**](http://jsfiddle.net/671474hx/)

Comment: Off topic: Rather than that noConflict business, you could just do this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(...); });` Or, use the shorthand `jQuery(function($) { $(...); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/671474hx/4/):

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    //reset
    $(".addClass").prop("checked", false);
    $(".addClass").click(function () {

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

            //checked
            $(this).addClass("selected");

        } else {
            //unchecked
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }

    })

});
```

Using this as the form:

```
<input class="addClass" name="mycheckbox[]" value="xxx" type="checkbox">&nbsp;xxx
<br />
<input class="addClass" name="mycheckbox[]" value="yyy" type="checkbox">&nbsp;yyy
```

Making it easier to select the appropriate checkboxes and inverted your if-statement.